# Images in a web application won't show up until it's redeployed?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, image-uploading

I'm working on a project for my web development class, it's a basic image upload / search system. Users can upload the images successfully, the only problem is they won't show up in a search until I redeploy the web app! The link is there with the correct image paths, everything is correct in the database, but it will 404 if I click on it unless I redeploy the web application.

I'm not sure what kind of code I could show you guys for this, and it's hard to find a google result for the issue.

the server I'm using is weblogic built into jdeveloper (most recent version, 11g I think?)

My guess is it doesn't scan the directories that have the images until it starts the app, therefore anything added after the initial deploy won't show up. Is there any way to force it to scan the directory after a successful upload?

Comment: Where exactly are you saving the images? Do you close the output stream after writing to it?

Comment: They're saved in a directory called uploads/ that's under public_html.  I'm using an apache library for file uploading. http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/, I checked the behavior of the function I'm using and it looks like it is not necessary to close the stream because I'm writing the file directly to it's final location. (See their section on processing uploaded items and the write() function)

Comment: `public_html`? Are you using Apache HTTPD as proxy and image server?

Comment: No..the weblogic server is the only server. It's some thing that's built into Oracle Jdeveloper (the IDE I'm using)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use that web server? Try tomcat and see if you get the same issue. I take it btw that by redeploy your mean you have to stop and restart the server? Does that process copy your webapp to another part of your disk so the web server is looking in a "mirror" dir instead of at the original webapp dir? That could be the issue

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response but I can't use Tomcat. This is for a school project so I'm stuck with what they've told us to use =/ It's due tomorrow and at this point I'm not bothering to fix it. It may knock a percent or two off the project but overall I don't think it'll be a huge issue. Obviously if this was a real-world application it would be a big issue lol